# how to reset spacing, using the package of bu_ece_thesis.sty

Tags: spacing, packages

I am a new user of SWP 5.5 (Scientific Workplace).

I am writing thesis. For simplicity, I directly used the template of "Boston University ECE" (File-new-thesis-Boston University ECE).

Now I want to reset the default spacing to double spacing. I tried several ways from Internet, but failed, with the error:

> ! LaTeX Error: Command \setstretch already defined.
>                  Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

I really do not know how to solve this problem. Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You will have to give us a minimal code of your document which shows your problem. You say, you have tried several things. Which things? You can prevent us from doing the same mistakes as you a second time by providing this information. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using `\setstretch{2}` or something else?

Comment: Yeah!!I guess so~~~ Do you have idea about how to do?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi, I will post a minimal code soon.

Comment: It sounds like you're actually trying to redefine the `\setstretch` macro. Is this the case?

Comment: Hi and welcome, ew things: Do not change a package. If you violate the specifications of the university they will reject your thesis. The package might have the functionality built in, look in the documentation.

Comment: @Mico, I think this is the case~~~

Comment: Thank all of you!! I guess I have already fixed the problem! add a latex field and reset \setstretch. It is my first time posting in this community. so helpful, Thanks~

Comment: @Bea -- it might help someone else if you explain (either in an edit to the question, or as a self-answer) what exactly the problem was, and how you fixed it.  otherwise, this is a candidate for closure.

Comment: @barbarabeeton,

Comment: Problem: 
reset spacing using the thesis template of "Boston University ECE". 
Here are what I tried:
    1) add "setspace" package through "option and package", and reset the spacing to double spacing. By then the package in use are "amsmath, amstonts.amssymb, apalike, float.subfigure, option2, facyheading,fancybox, bu_ece_thesis." However, when I compiled, an error arose:

Comment: c:\swp55\TCITeX/tex/latex/contrib/subfigure/subfigure.cfg))
    (c:\swp55\TCITeX/tex/latex/contrib/caption/caption2.sty)
    (c:\swp55\TCITeX/tex/latex209/contrib/fancyheadings/fancyheadings.sty)
    (c:\swp55\TCITeX/tex/latex/contrib/fancybox/fancybox.sty

Comment: Style option: `fancybox' v1.3 <2000/09/19> (tvz)
    ) (c:\swp55\TCITeX/tex/latex/SWmisc/bu_ece_thesis/bu_ece_thesis.sty
    (c:\swp55\TCITeX/tex/latex209/contrib/misc/doublespace.sty))
    (c:\swp55\TCITeX/tex/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.sty
    (c:\swp55\TCITeX/tex/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.cfg))
    (c:\swp55\TCITeX/tex/latex/contrib/setspace/setspace.sty
    Package: `setspace' 6.7 <2000/12/01>
    ! LaTeX Error: Command \setstretch already defined.
     Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

Comment: 2) add "setspace" package--add latex field (\doublespace)--compile, some problems arose.

   3) I guessed it was because I used the package of "bu_ece_thesis" and all this parameters were defined in that package (I am a really new user). So I wanted to edit the package of "bu_ece_thesis" and posted this question here.

Comment: Solution:
Just add a latex field, and use \setstretch{2}.

Comment: Please post an answer that is a bit more readable than comments (no real code markup).

Comment: I just looked at the file: It is for the long deprecated (20 years) LaTeX2.09 and should *not* be used. Please ask the maintainers to update the package.

Comment: Found a slightly newer version (though the header is the same) at http://www.bu.edu/ece/?attachment_id=20072. Still, please ask them to update.